# Pegar todos dados selecionados com javascript em campo select múltiplo

Tags: jquery, html, select, bootstrap-3

Vou descrever o que estou tentando fazer:

Existem setores, e em cada setor há diversos funcionários, e eu preciso que, ao selecionar um setor em um campo `select`, o próximo campo `select` (que listará os funcionários) seja preenchido com os funcionários deste setor.

O problema é que pode ser possível selecionar mais de um setor (o campo setor é *multiple*), ou seja, ao selecionar 2 setores diferentes, o campo `select` de funcionários deverá ser carregado com os funcionários destes 2 setores.

Não estou sabendo como enviar todos os IDs dos setores para o meu arquivo `PHP` que irá devolver o código com todos os funcionários.

segue jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t0u1j6L8/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloca o atributo `multiple` no select e depois usa `$(this).val()` para saber os valores selecionados. Assim

```
$.post('_require/_jp/jpcarregafuncionario.php', {
        id_fun: $(this).val()
    }, function(res) {
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t0u1j6L8/6/